# extracting information from rows in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am working with a csv file that in one column will have an ID number that I have saved in a dictionary like this:

---

ID  Round

1     1

1     2

1     3

2     4

2     5

3     6

---

ID_rounds = {1: [], 2: [], 3: []}

I then want the code to go through every row in my csv file, and for the every row, add the round number to the correct list in the dictionary.

So the final result will look like:
ID_rounds = {1:{1,2,3], 2:[4,5], 3:[6]}

Answer (score 0):

Import your data into a list and simply iterate over it assigning the dict `key` and `value` per iteration.

```
with open('tt.csv', 'r') as file:
  headers = file.readline()
  data = [row.strip().split(',') for row in file.readlines()]    

d = {}

for key, value in data:
  if key in d.keys():
    d[key].append(value)
  else:
    d[key] = [value]
```

Output:

```
d
{'1': ['1', '2', '3'], '2': ['4', '5'], '3': ['6']}
```

Comment: Some might write `d.setdefault(key, []).append(value)` instead of a 4-line `if`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `defaultdict` (from the `collections` module) for this:

```
from io import StringIO
from collections import defaultdict

data = '''ID Round
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 4
2 5
3 6
'''

# initialize default dict (each dict value is an empty list)
dd = defaultdict(list)

lines = StringIO(data)

# skip header
_ = next(lines)

# process body
for line in lines:
    key, value = line.rstrip('\n').split()
    key = int(key)
    value = int(value)
    dd[key].append(value)
    
# show results    
print(dict(dd))

{1: [1, 2, 3], 2: [4, 5], 3: [6]}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df = pd.read_csv('your_csv_file.csv', sep=' ')
result = df.groupby("ID").Round.apply(list).to_dict()
```